# Laravel queryScope relacionados

Tags: laravel, buscador

Estoy necesitando de su ayuda para realizar un buscador en laravel relacionado.

Tengo una vista con un formulario donde el usuario puede seleccionar las categorías y escribir una ubicación.

```
{{ Form::open(['route' => 'busquedas', 'method' => 'get', 'class' => 'form-inline'])}}

                <select id="categoria" name="categoria" class="form-control">
                    {{-- <option value="" disabled>Seleccionar</option> --}}
                    @foreach($categorias as $index => $categoria)
                        <option value="{{ $categoria->nombre_categoria }}">
                            {{ $categoria->nombre_categoria }}
                        </option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ Form::text('ubicacion', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '¿Que ubicación está buscando? ']) }}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default question-btn">
                        <span class="fa fa-search">Buscar</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            
            {{ Form::close() }}
```

En el controlador de forma separada obtengo lo que el usuario está buscando.

```
 $categoriaObtenida = Category::with('properties')->where('nombre_categoria', $categoria)->get();

    $ubicacionesObtenida = Ubicacion::with('properties')
        ->ubicacion($ubicacion)
        ->get();

    $areasObtenidas = Area::with('properties')
        ->area($ubicacion)
        ->get();
```

Pero lo que necesito es un poco más complicado, es tener todas las PROPIEDADES en base a la categoría seleccionada y la ubicación escrita por el usuario.

En el modelo tengo las siguientes relaciones:

MODELO PROPIEDADES y RELACIONES

```
public function ubicacion(){
    return $this->hasMany(Ubicacion::class);
}


public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }
```

MODELO UBICACION y RELACIONES

```
public function properties(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Property::class);
}

public function area(){
    //hasOne: una ubicacion tiene un area
    return $this->hasOne(Area::class);
}
```

MODELO CATEGORIA y RELACIONES

```
public function properties(){
    return $this->hasMany(Property::class);
}
```

Me podrían brindar una mano por favor. Es muy importante para mi. Muchas gracias

Comment: Agrega por favor una mejor explicación de las relaciones entre tus entidades

Comment: Hola @BetaM agregue los modelos por favor avísame si es claro o necesitas más información. Te lo agradezco de corazón!

Comment: Creo que tus relaciones estan mal definidas, por que en el modelo `Ubicacion` usas el método `belongsToMany` que se aplica a una relación muchos a muchos, entonces ¿una ubicación tiene muchas propiedades a varias ubicaciones tienen varias propiedades?, cuando ese punto quede aclarado y subsanado podemos seguir avanzando

Comment: Hola @BetaM agradezco mucho tu indicación y me gustaría un poco más de tu ayuda si puede ser. Pensé mejor el modelo y me di cuenta que no era belongsToMany si no hasMany y recupero bien la información. Gracias a ti di un gran paso. Me puedes brindar un poco más de luz de como sería el tramo de unir las dos consultas. $categoriaObtenida = Category::with('properties')->where('nombre_categoria', $categoria)->get();

        $ubicacionesObtenida = Ubicacion::with('properties')
            ->ubicacion($ubicacion)
            ->get(); ¿Puede ser?

Comment: Edita por favor tu pregunta y agrega las correcciones asi como una mejor descripción de las relaciones entre tus tablas

Comment: Hola @BetaM por supuesto, acabo de editar. Agregué el controlador como lo tengo hasta el momento.